# Typescript complaining about the input to be null when i have implicit check

Tags: typescript

I have something as simple as this in my code

```
const baseAntcsStorageKey = 'abv' 
const userId:string=  localStorage.getItem(baseAntcsStorageKey) ? localStorage.getItem(baseAntcsStorageKey) :  "missing_userId"
```

but typescript keeps giving me following error

> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'null'
>   is not assignable to type 'string'

When I am doing a check that if the value is not there, assign an empty string.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

When Typescript sees a `getItem` call, it will understand that it will either return `null` or a string. It **doesn't** "memoize" the call into its type-checker - any time you call `getItem`, even with the same parameter, Typescript assumes that the return value will be `string | null`.

If the item there, if it exists in storage, will always be truthy, use `||` instead:

```
const userId: string =  localStorage.getItem(baseAntcsStorageKey) || "missing_userId";
```

If the item may exist, but be the empty string, another option would be to save the `getItem` result in a variable first:

```
const storageItem = localStorage.getItem(baseAntcsStorageKey);
const userId: string = storageItem === null ? "missing_userId" : storageItem;
```

In general, the same return value cannot be assumed for the same call of a function, because there's no guarantee that a function is pure. For an example function which returns `string | null` but does not return the same value each time, consider:

```
let flag = false;
const getItem = () => {
  flag = !flag;
  return flag ? 'foo' : null;
};
```

Here, if `getItem` is called once, with a parameter, it'll return something *different* if it's called again with the same parameter, and Typescript has no way of knowing whether an arbitrary function has this sort of impure property.

Comment: Better than my answer, since my answer would propagate undefined behaviour by allowing null value to userId.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that `userid` is of type string or null, which is incompatible with `localstoragegetItem()` which is of type string only.

You can change userId's type to string|null.

```
const userId:string|null =  localStorage.getItem(baseAntcsStorageKey) ? localStorage.getItem(baseAntcsStorageKey) :  "missing_userId"
```